# Zygmund functions are Holder

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

We say that $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Zygmund if

$$f(x)+f(y)-2f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\mathrm{O}(|x-y|),$$

and we say that $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder, $\alpha>0$ if there is $C>0$ such that
$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}\leq C$$ for all $x,y\in[a,b], x\not=y.$

I would like to show that if $f$ is Zygmund then $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder for any $0<\alpha<1.$

I try to start the quotient of Holder definition and add and subtract terms to get the expression of Zygmund definition but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of the Zygmund class is incomplete! In fact we all know there exist *discontinuous* functions $f$ with $$f(x)+f(y)-2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=0,$$so $$f(x)+f(y)-2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=O(x-y)\tag{*}$$cannot imply that $f$ is $Lip_\alpha$, since it doesn't even imply $f$ is continuous.

The right definition is that $f\in Zyg$ if $f$ is *continuous* and satisfies $(*)$. It seems hugely curious to me that although $(*)$ does not imply continuity, $(*)$ *plus* continuity imply a specific bound on the modulus of continuity:

> > **Prop.** If $f\in Zyg$ then $f(x+h)-f(x)=O(h\log(1/h))$ for $0<h<1$.

In the proper context this is almost simple: If one knows about Besov spaces one can use one of various characterizations to show that $Zyg=B^1_{\infty,\infty}$, and then show that the proposition follows from another characterization.

Or one can give a farily simple *ad hoc* proof starting from nothing. Or some ones can, we're about to find out whether I can:

Let's define $$||f||_*=\sup_{x\ne y} \left|\frac{f(x)+f(y)-2f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)}{x-y}\right|$$and $$s(x,y)=\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}.$$Note that $$s(x,y)=\frac{s(x,(x+y)/2)+s((x+y)/2,y)}{2}$$and
$$||f||_*=\sup_{x\ne y}\left|\frac{s(x,(x+y)/2)-s((x+y)/2,y)}{2}\right|,$$so that

> > **Lemma.** $|s(x,(x+y)/2)|\le||f||_\infty+|s(x,y)|.$

Now for the details that I leave to you: You can use the lemma to prove the proposition for $h=2^{-n}$ by induction. Now if $h$ is a dyadic rational writing $h$ as the sum of finitely many distinct powers of $2$ gives what you want by just the triangle inequality. And finally the fact that $f$ is continuous allows you to remove the restriction that $h$ be a dyadic rational.

Comment: It is indeed curious that ($\ast$) and continuity together are so much stronger than both properties separately. But then again, continuous (or even only measurable) solutions of the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ are also much more regular than just continuous, yet there are also non-measurable solutions.

Comment: I try to prove that $f(x+\delta)-f(x)=\mathrm{O}(\delta\log(1/\delta))$ in the following way:  Define $g(\tau)=f(x+\tau)-f(x)$ for $0<\tau<\gamma.$ Apply the definition of zygmund function we have that: $g(\tau)-2g(\tau/2)=\mathrm{O}(\tau)$, $2g(\tau/2)-2^2g(\tau/2^2)=\mathrm{O}(\tau),$ ..., $2^{n-1}g(\tau/2^{n-1})-2^ng(\tau/2^n)=\mathrm{O}(\tau).$ Adding this terms we have that $$g(\tau)-2^ng(\tau/2^n)=n\mathrm{O}(\tau).$$ Now put $\tau=2^nh$ we have $$|g(h)|\leq \frac{M}{2^n}+\frac{n\mathrm{2^nh}}{2^n},$$ where $M=sup|g(x)|.$ Now if $\tau=2^nh\leq \gamma$ how I prove that $n=O(\log(1/h))$?

Comment: Where have $n2^nh$ read $nO(2^nh).$

Comment: @David Hi, is there a reference that I can see the Prop and $B^{1}_{\infty, \infty} = Zyg$. Thanks a lot.